# How do I use BernoulliNB?

Tags: python, bernoulli-probability

I'm trying to use BernoulliNB. Using the same data to train and to test, I get predictions other than the training data and probabilities other than 1. Why is that please?

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
BNB = BernoulliNB()

# Data
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'O' : [1,2,3,1,1,3,1,2,2,1],
                     'I1': [1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1],
                     'I2': [0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0],
                     'I3': [1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]})

df_I = df_1.iloc[:,1:4]
S_O  = df_1['O']

# Bernoulli Naive Bayes Classifier
A_F = BNB.fit(df_I, S_O)
A_P = BNB.predict(df_I)
A_R = BNB.predict_proba(df_I)

df_P = pd.DataFrame(A_P)
df_R = pd.DataFrame(A_R)

df_P.columns = ['Predicted A']
df_R.columns = ['Prob 1', 'Prob 2', 'Prob 3']

df_1 = df_1.join(df_P)
df_1 = df_1.join(df_R)
```

*Results*

```
O   I1  I2  I3  Predicted A Prob 1  Prob 2  Prob 3
1   1   0   1   1           .80     .15     .05
2   0   0   0   2           .59     .33     .08
3   0   1   0   3           .18     .39     .43
1   1   0   0   1           .59     .33     .08
1   0   0   0   2           .59     .33     .08
3   0   1   0   3           .18     .39     .43
1   1   0   1   1           .80     .15     .48
2   1   0   0   1           .59     .33     .08
2   0   1   0   3           .18     .39     .43
1   1   0   0   1           .59     .33     .08
```

I have tried to describe what I am trying to do, here:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/367829/how-probable-is-a-set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working correctly and you're using it right (code-wise). `Predicted A` is the predicted class label. In your case, the possible labels are defined by `O` and are `1,2,3` and `Predicted A` will always have values drawn from that set.

For probabilities, there is no guarantee they will be `=1`, in fact they almost never will be.

I think your confusion stems from the fact that you are feeding it known training data and yet the output is different? My guess is your *training data is too small here*, so it comes out slightly off. Feeding it more data will increase it's accuracy on this known training set.

I'll note that what you really want is to *feed it a large known training set, and then predict an unknown test dataset*. I can maybe get into the details of why that is, but I'd recommend reading tutorials on classifiers (scikit docs aren't bad, but any tutorial should cover this).

Code-wise, everything looks good to me.

Comment: I tried varying the data and worked out that _Prob 1_ is the probability that A=1 etc. so that _Predicted A_ is whichever of the probabiliy colums is highest.

Comment: That's correct :). If you dig through the source you'll see they just assign the label according to the `argmax` of the probs, basically. Given enough training data I think you can get the prediction of the *known* data to be very very accurate - the real question is will it work on the test data.

Comment: I'm struggling to get it to work on the test data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55187516/look-up-bernoullinb-probability-in-dataframe